# Ember.js - New and Edit routes with the same templates

Tags: ember.js

I have a wizard like set up for creating a new model like this:

```
WZ.StepsRoute = Em.Route.extend
  renderTemplate: ->
    @render 'exercises/new'
  model: ->
    WZ.Exercise.createRecord()

WZ.StepsOneRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @modelFor 'steps'
  renderTemplate: ->
    @render 'exercises/stepsone'

WZ.StepsTwoRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @modelFor 'steps'
  renderTemplate: ->
    @render 'exercises/stepstwo'
```

This works great but what if I wanted to enter the StepsOneRoute/StepsTwoRoute from an edit route?

How could I conditionally pull the existing model from an edit route rather than pull the stepsRoute currentModel which returns a new record?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some controller, which will store the current model.
`StepsRoute` will create a new model and set it to that controller, Edit route will get the model to edit and set it to that controller, and `StepsOneRoute` and `StepsTwoRoute` routes will retrieve it from that controller.